# Fastest way of taking the average of each element which has the same value?

Tags: python

I'm not quite sure how to formulate this question. I'm almost certain this will have been asked before, but I can't find it.

I have some data, like:

```
x = np.random.rand(100) * 0.0001
y = [round(i, 1) for i in np.random.rand(100)]
```

They are both 100 elements long. However, `y` contains only about 10 unique elements.For each unique element in `y`, I want to take the average of all the numbers in `x` at the same position.

Something like:

```
averageX = []
for unique in set(y):
    items = []
    for i in y:
         if i == unique:         # For each copy of this number
              items.append(x[i]) # take all the items in x at that index
    averageX.append(mean(items)) # and take the average
```

What would be the best pythonic way to do this?

Comment: you just gave the answer in your question - find indexes of those 10 unique items in y - sum elements with those indexes in x and divide by 10 - that's your avg

Comment: @Drako Yeah. I can solve it myself, but double looping and an if-statement doesn't seem particularly efficient when I'm working with thousands of list with lots of elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you convert to pandas you can take advantage of `groupby`

```
x = np.random.rand(100) * 0.0001
y = [round(i, 1) for i in np.random.rand(100)]

import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame([x,y]).transpose().rename(columns={0:'x',1:'y'})
df.groupby(['y']).mean()

#Output:
#0.0  0.000019
#0.1  0.000046
#0.2  0.000051
#0.3  0.000049
#0.4  0.000031
#0.5  0.000043
#0.6  0.000051
#0.7  0.000049
#0.8  0.000044
#0.9  0.000053
#1.0  0.000034
```

Answer (score 2):

So... `x` is some data, `y` is a category map of sorts mapping each index of `x` to a category, and you need per-category averages?

```
import collections
import random

x = [random.randint(0, 100) for i in range(100)]  # data
y = [random.randint(0, 10) for i in range(100)]  # categories

data_per_category = collections.defaultdict(list)

for category, datum in zip(y, x):  # iterate in parallel over both y and x
    data_per_category[category].append(datum)

for category, data in data_per_category.items():
    print(category, sum(data) / len(data))
```

This prints out (e.g.)

```
9 51.2
5 49.0
8 56.75
1 48.166666666666664
7 45.0
0 38.42857142857143
3 50.333333333333336
4 43.7
6 45.4
10 53.0
2 44.583333333333336
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the efficiency, but you can use masking:

```
means = {}
for i in y:
    if i not in means:
        means[i] = x[y == i].mean()
```

Another way, probably somewhat more efficient, is sorting:

```
data = np.stack((x, y), axis=0)
data = data[np.lexsort(data), :]
```

Now the split is sequential, so you can do something as *simple* as

```
 breaks = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(data[:, 1]))
 start = np.concatenate(([0], breaks))
 end = np.concatenate((breaks, [data.shape[0]]))
 means = np.add.reduceat(data[:, 0], start) / (end - start)
```

In the sorted data, a non-zero diff in `y` indicates a new value of `y`. You can use that to compute the indices of the start and end of each segment in `x` that has the same `y` value. The sums of the segments are given by [`reduceat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) between the start indices.